# Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, i, succ, value = 1) : subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, function, subscript

I have to simulate an image with a white crack on a black background. So I defined a function that adds to a matrix with all elements equal to zero some consecutive points equal to one. 
The function is the following:

```
crepa<-function(matrice) {
 start<-sample(1:ncol(matrice),1)
 matrice[1,start]<-1
 for (i in 2:nrow(matrice)) {
  alpha<-sample(c(-1,0,1),1)
  succ<-start+alpha
  if (succ==(ncol(matrice)+1)) succ==ncol(matrice)
  if (succ==0) succ==1
  matrice[i,succ]<-1
  start<-succ
 }
 matrice<-as.matrix(matrice)
 }
```

To control whether the function works well, I applied it over and over again to the following matrix:

```
 m<-matrix(0,64,64)
 imma<-crepa(m)

 par(mar=rep(0,4))
 image(t(imma), axes = FALSE, col = grey(seq(0, 1, length = 256)))
```

In most cases the result is correct. However, in few cases I run into this Error:

> Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, i, succ, value = 1) : subscript out of bounds

Answer (score 1):

These two lines:

```
  if (succ==(ncol(matrice)+1)) succ==ncol(matrice)
  if (succ==0) succ==1
```

Should be:

```
  if (succ==(ncol(matrice)+1)) succ=ncol(matrice)
  if (succ==0) succ=1
```

In case you still can't see it, you've used the equality test `==` when you should use assignment `=` or `<-`.

The error message told me it had to be the element going off the matrix, so I started printing out the values of `succ` and then noticed it wasn't being reset within the right range, and only *then* did I spot the mistake. I probably looked at the code ten times without noticing. I also figured that kind of error was more likely with a small matrix, and so tested with a 6x6 matrix which meant I could be more likely to see it than with a 64x64!

Comment: I wanted to post the exact same answer just some seconds later. ;-) Good comment about the small matrix. I had another way of tracking it down: Wrapped the script in a for loop and hoped that it will break. (which it did quite fast..) The debugger stopped one line below the lines with the equality test, then I saw the `==` immediatly.

Comment: Now it's ok. Thanks!